Does ADX ".drop extents" command physically delete data from storage (hard delete, not soft delete)?
I want to be able to physically delete a table and all of its data from ADX.  (My retention policy is currently set to indefinite.)
There are a number of different ways to "delete" or "drop" data from ADX, but many of them are only a soft delete, leaving data in storage.
The .purge command is one option to physically remove data.  I think the ".purge table allrecords" command could be a solution that would probably not come with the cost/performance implications when applying it to an entire table like it does when applying it to only a subset of records.  (Interested to know if that is actually true or not - if .purge could be a good solution for physical deletion of an entire table.)  But I'm not quite sure if I want to make the case for enabling the .purge command on a cluster, which I think is disabled by default.
That leaves me looking at the .drop extents command as a potential solution.
The question I have is whether the ".drop extents" command actually physically deletes data from underlying storage, or if it is another soft delete approach?  The documentation around this seems to be lacking in clarity to me.


Does ADX ".drop extents" command physically delete data from storage?

no. it's a soft delete operation.
the physical artifacts of the dropped (soft-deleted) extents (data shards) will be hard-deleted at a later time, based on the value of the Recoverability property in the table's effective retention policy

Looking at this Recoverability property, it is just a boolean yes/no, as to whether the data will be recoverable for 14 days after soft delete.  Does that Recoverability property also apply to the other soft delete mechanisms such as dropping a table or deleting records?  Will those also be hard deleted based on this after 14 days if it is enabled?  If this property is set to "No", does that mean that all soft deletes are effectively hard deletes?


for data to be recoverable for 14d, it's not going to be hard deleted during that 14d period. if you're not purging data, there's no guarantee for when artifacts of dropped (soft-deleted) extents will be hard deleted after the recoverability period has passed, but it's likely to be a short period afterwards. 2) soft deletes are not hard deletes, under any configuration. 3) the recoverability period applies to any extents (data shards) that were dropped (soft-deleted), either due to retention or due to accidentally dropping a table. 3) purged and soft-deleted records are not recoverable.

